# How to add a category to comments?

Tags: comment-form, comment-meta

I am currently trying to add a category to the comments on my wordpress site. I already added a title to these and tried several ways to add a dropdown (selection) list to the comment form but I am not good in php and I always receive an error msg...

Here is what I am using in functions.php to add the title field:

```
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'additional_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'additional_fields' );
function additional_fields () {
echo '<p class="comment-form-title">'.
'<label for="title">' . __( 'Titre (Je peux...)' ) . '</label>'.
'<input id="title" name="title" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';
}
```

and here is what I use to save the data:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' ); 
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
if ( ( isset( $_POST['title'] ) ) && ( $_POST['title'] != '') ) 
$title = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['title']);
add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'title', $title );
}
```

Would anybody know how I could adapt these codes to add another meta field as a selection list of, let's say, 2 possible values? I have well read this topic here [Add a drop down list to comment form?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101579/add-a-drop-down-list-to-comment-form) but I don't undertsand the very long answer...

Thanks a billion times in advance for your help... (I ve been stuck on these for days now)
Sincerely,

Thierry

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally made it following [this crystal clear tut](http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-drop-down-menu-for-wordpress-custom-fields)

Consequently, my `functions.php` became:

```
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'additional_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'additional_fields' );

function additional_fields () {
  echo '<p class="comment-form-title">'.
  '<label for="title">' . __( 'Titre (Je peux...)' ) . '</label>'.
  '<input id="title" name="title" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';

  echo '<strong><label for="category">Cette solution est particulièrement utile...</label></strong>
    <select id="category" name="category">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Tous">Dans tous les cas</option>
        <option value="Argent">Sans argent</option>
        <option value="Temps">Sans le temps</option>
        <option value="Santé">Sans la santé</option>
    </select>';

}


add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' );
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
  if ( ( isset( $_POST['title'] ) ) && ( $_POST['title'] != '') )
  $title = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['title']);
  add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'title', $title );
  if ( ( isset( $_POST['category'] ) ) && ( $_POST['category'] != '') )
  $category = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['category']);
  add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'category', $category );

}
```

I hope it'll help